# python replace self with pickle.loads

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I use pickle to instantiate objects，How to solve the problem of no successful assignment?

Is there something wrong with my use of the picke.loads and picke.dumps step?

mycode

```
import pickle


class A():
    def __init__(self, nid):
        self.nid = nid
        self._data_dict = {}

    def initData(self, nid, pickle_data=None):
        if nid == 2:
            print("use picke")
            self = pickle.loads(pickle_data)
            print(f"pickle loads _data_dict:{self._data_dict}")
        else:
            print("normal")
            self._data_dict['key'] = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(1)
    a.initData(1)
    print(f"a _data_dict::{a._data_dict}")
    pickle_data = pickle.dumps(a, 0)

    print('-'*100)
    b = A(2)
    b.initData(2, pickle_data)
    print(f"b _data_dict::{b._data_dict}")
```

result

```
normal
a _data_dict::{'key': 1}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
use picke
pickle loads _data_dict:{'key': 1}
b _data_dict::{}
```

Comment: Do you only expect the pickle to store the `_data_dict`, or the whole object? Because if you want the whole object, just writing `b = pickle.loads(pickle_data)` at the top level is best. If you only want to be pickling `_data_dict`, you need to change your dumping code, in addition to your loading code.

Comment: i expect pickle the whole object,    When I've pickle.dumps an object's data, I want to instantiate the object directly with pickle.loads, rather than re-instantiating an object.

Comment: I don't think I understand the distinction you're drawing between instantiating and reinstantiating. There is only one chance to create an object. Once it's created, you could reassign your attributes to match some other object, but `pickle` isn't designed for that, so you'll end up doing most of it manually. There's no way to just unpack the attributes of a pickled object, you're going to get a whole object and you'll have to pick it apart afterwards. `self = pickle.loads(pickle_data)` only rebinds the name `self` inside the `initData` method, it doesn't effect the original object at all.

Comment: Is there any way to do something similar? Since there is a class that takes a lot of time per instantiation, I use pickle.loads to save time。
At present, it takes about 10s for my class to instantiate, and it only takes about 0.5s to use pickle.loads. The purpose of this is to minimize the modification of the previous code

Comment: Don't do `b = B(whatever)` and then try to add one some extra step to deal with the pickle data. That's too late, you've already paid the instantiation cost. Just do `B = pickle.loads(pickle_data)` and directly create the object from the pickle data. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254), where you have a real problem (e.g. "My class takes too long to instantiate"), but you're asking about your attempted solution, which doesn't make much sense to anyone, and might not even solve your real problem, even if you could make it work.